# How to disable autoplay of audio (stream) html5 element

Tags: html, audio, autoplay

I can't make this work, and I tried multiple methods, so far the suggestions maybe worked for static mp3 and other files, but for this stream, with controlls hidden I couldn't stop the autoplay, anything I tried.

Please check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5350dbuu/)

```
<audio id="player" autostart="0" autostart="false" name="media"><source id="liveatc_source" src="http://mtl2.liveatc.net/lrsb" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

PS. it's a stream but you will probably not hear anything, unless there is some activity in my area, but to see if the stream autoplays or not, I used Inspect of Google chrome, and than check the Network tab, you will see the stream is loading coninously...

[screenshot stream loading continously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlygy.gif)

Answer (score 8):

The solution was to use preload atribute like this:

```
<audio id="player" autostart="0" autostart="false" preload ="none" name="media">
```